# Printing out each number from a multi-dimensional array without comma after last number?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, iteration

I'm trying to figure out how to display each number from the same "row" of a multi-dimenional array on a sigle line, with a comma to seperate them.

This is how I've declared the multi-dimensional array

```
int[][] grid = {
            {1, 2, 3},
            {4},
            {5, 6},
            {123, 4567, 78901, 234567}
    };
```

This is the loop I use to display each "row" on a separate line with the comma's between them:

```
for(int[] row: grid){
        for(int col: row){
            System.out.print(col + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Alternatively:

```
for(int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++){
            System.out.print(grid[row][col] + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

It all works fine, but the last number from each "row" gets the comma as well, result:

```
1, 2, 3, 
4, 
5, 6, 
123, 4567, 78901, 234567,
```

How can I make it so that the last number does not get a comma?

Comment: Only print the comma when `col < grid[row].length -1 `

Comment: Quick: `System.out.print((col>0?", ":"") + grid[row][col]);` (better options are possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, and easily, you can do:

```
for(String s : Arrays.deepToString(grid).split("(?<=]), "))
{
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]",""));
}
```

Here:

- `Arrays.deepToString` will return the array as a String.
- `.split("(?<=]), ")` will split it where the 1-d arrays (in the `grid`) end.
- `s.replaceAll("[\\]\\[]","")` will remove all the `[` and `]`, which are present in the String returned by `Arrays.deepToString`